# How to populate a second list with data from a file

Tags: c#, list, serialization, deserialization

So basically I have a register form which when filled a file will be created and populated with the details entered from the register form.

I am trying to create another list which will be populated with the data from the file by using deserialization but I`m not managing to do this.

here is the code for the deserialization.

```
    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //List<Person> pList2 = new List<Person>();
        Stream s2 = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<Person> pList2 = new List<Person>();
        bf.Deserialize(s2);
        foreach (Person p in pList2)
        {
            bf.Deserialize(s2);
        }
        s2.Close();

    }
```

Comment: "Not able to" is not a proper problem description. Explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens. You also need to show your serialization code. You also don't do anything with the result of the deserialization, like `object deserialized = bf.Deserialize(s2)`.

Comment: it looks as the pList2 is empty for me

Comment: What i am trying to do is by using a register form i Create a list of users that will be saved into a file, and then creating another list in the login form which will be populated by reading the details in the file. To login the user will enter the username and password which the program will compare with the details from the file.

Comment: This is the code for the serialization:

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pList.Add(new Person(txtboxName.Text, txtboxSurname.Text, (int.Parse(txtboxAge.Text)), txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxUsername.Text, txtboxPassword.Text));



            foreach (Person per in pList)
            {
                Stream s = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Append);
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(s, per);
                s.Close();
            }

            this.Close();

        }

Comment: You need to explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens. Your question comes down to "this doesn't work" and leaves the reader to guess what exactly doesn't work. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you aren't saving the data from the Deserialization. Might want to edit it to be something like this.

```
var pList2 = (List<Person>) bf.Deserialize(s2);
```

Then you can iterate over the contents of `pList2`.

Also an excellent example of BinaryFormatter here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did this but pList2 is still "null"

Comment: Does the file contain anything?
Can you update your code to reflect the changes?

Answer (score -1):

The following link explains how the BinaryFormatter works 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Please find Below an updated code block based on the question

```
    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream s2 = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<Person> pList2 = (List<Person>)bf.Deserialize(s2); //Deserialize here no need to set to a new list first.

        //Loop not required for Deserialize as it was stored as a list at this point all people will be available
        //foreach (Person p in pList2)
        //{

        //}

        s2.Close();

    }
```

Comment: This has no relation whatsoever to the question, other than "How to use BinarySerializer", which is not the question.